# SQL - Comparing dates in a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do I obtain the revised table from the original table using SQL? Basically, what I wanted to do is to compare the rows of customer data based on the date. Customers who purchased any item within 15 days in a month will be considered to make 1 purchase. For instance, for customer Paolo Arcotti, although he made 3 purchases within 15 days, only the first purchase is considered and is counted as 1 purchase; while for customer Hanna Moss, this is considered as 2 purchases. In short, I would like to categorise purchases from 1-15 Jan as 1 purchase and 16-30 as another purchase.

[Original Table vs Revised Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3rE1.png)

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What have you already tried? Also what database technology are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases support date functions, but each database is different.  The following approach uses `not exists` and functions for the day, month, and year of a date:

```
select t.*
from original as t
where not exists (select 1
                  from original as t2
                  where t2.customer = t.customer and
                        datepart("yyyy", t2.date) = datepart("yyyy", t.date) and
                        datepart("m", t2.date) = datepart("m", t.date) and
                        t2.date < t.date and
                        ((datepart("d", t2.date) <= 15 and datepart("d", t.date) <= 15) or
                         (datepart("d", t2.date) > 15 and datepart("d", t.date) > 15)
                        )
                 );
```

Comment: how do I further remove duplicates from the results above? I noted a small mistake when the code above is used. For instance, if the same customer makes 3 purchases on the same day, the script will still calculate as 3 purchases instead of 1 most likely due to line no 8 -t2.date < t.date. I tried t2.date <= t.date but this doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: @saturday . . . A unique identifier for each row would help in removing such duplicates.  Do you want to ask another question with sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as 
(
select *,DATEPART(d,orderdate) as dayofmonth1,row_number() over(partition by customer order by customer,orderdate ) as rn from #test 
where DATEPART(d,orderdate)<=15
)
, cte1 as
(
select *,DATEPART(d,orderdate) as dayofmonth1,row_number() over(partition by customer order by customer,orderdate )as rn from #test 
where DATEPART(d,orderdate)>15
)
select *from cte where rn=1
union select *from cte1 where rn=1
```